# gfortran compiling error for openmp on windows

Tags: compilation, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I am trying to run a very simple openmp fortran 90 code, using windows 7 and gfortran. Here is my code

```
 PROGRAM HELLO
 ! USE omp_lib
   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS
   INTEGER OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS
   INTEGER OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM
   write(6,"(a, i3)") " OpenMP max threads: ", OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS()
 !$OMP PARALLEL
   write(6,"(2(a,i3))") " OpenMP: N_threads = ", &
        &   OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()," thread = ", OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
 !$OMP END PARALLEL
 END PROGRAM
```

And this is what I'm compiling with

```
 gfortran -fopenmp -g -J"bin" test.f90 -o test
```

And this is what happens:

```
 gfortran -fopenmp -g -J"bin" test.f90 -o test
 gfortran.exe: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
```

I believe I haven't set up my environment variables correctly, and I wanted to know if there is a way I can do this programmatically, or if anyone knows how they are supposed to be set up, assuming that is the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the `fortran` tag if you want to get more attention. Use `fortran90` in addition if you have something specific to this version what cannot be found in later ones.

Comment: If you run `gfortran -print-search-dirs`, the displayed `install:` line is where `gfortran` is looking for `libgomp.spec`. Do you have the `.spec` file somewhere else on your system? Could you move it to the displayed `install:` directory and try again? Note that you can totally redefine where `gfortran` looks by using the `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` environment variable: "If GCC_EXEC_PREFIX is set, it specifies a prefix to use in the names of the subprograms executed by the compiler."